# How to set zoom to fit circle in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry, google-maps-markers, zooming

We have distance search filter. It has a map viewport that allow to set base marker and a input text box that allows enter distance in kilometers.

We then add a [circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) to show this distance on the map.

How can I zoom the map so it fits the circle?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For multiple circles use **union** instead of **extend**:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

$.each(circles, function(index, circle){
    bounds.union(circle.getBounds());
});

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Nice. I've used this to ensure that *at least* the search radius circle is encompassed, then extended the bounds for any markers further out with latlngBounds.extend(marker.getPosition())

Answer (score 64):

A `google.maps.Circle` has a `getBounds()` method which returns the `LatLngBounds` of the circle. You may use this bounds as argument for `google.maps.Map.fitBounds()`

If using a circle, you can do this:

```
map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
```

...at the end of the init-function.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MHLjy/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MHLjy/)

Comment: This simple. Thank you. I did use map.fitBounds() but did not notice circule has getBounds. Very nice :)

Comment: This should be accepted as answer for this question