# How to fit a circle inside a Google Maps when using vue2-google-maps?

Tags: google-maps, vuejs2, vue2-google-maps

I found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768439/how-to-google-map-circles-fit-the-map) that you can use fitBounds() to make a circle fit into a map. I tried to use it while using vue2-google-maps and it didn't work. How would be the equivalent for it while using this library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that matter Google Maps Circle object could be accessed via `$refs` attribute:

```
<GmapCircle
    ref="circleRef" 
    :center="{ lat: 52.521248, lng: 13.399038 }"
    :radius="400000"
    :visible="true"
    :options="{fillColor:'blue',fillOpacity:0.2}"
/>
```

and then map viewport set the circle bounds like this:

```
mounted: function() {
    this.$refs.circleRef.$circlePromise.then(() => {
        const {$circleObject} = this.$refs.circleRef; //get google.maps.Circle object
        const map = $circleObject.getMap(); //get map instance 
        map.fitBounds($circleObject.getBounds());
   })
}
```

**Example**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap :center="center" :zoom="zoom">
      <GmapCircle
        ref="circleRef" 
        :center="{ lat: 52.521248, lng: 13.399038 }"
        :radius="400000"
        :visible="true"
        :options="{fillColor:'blue',fillOpacity:0.2}"
      ></GmapCircle>
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 5,
      center: { lat: 59.339025, lng: 18.065818 }
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.$refs.circleRef.$circlePromise.then(() => {
        const {$circleObject} = this.$refs.circleRef; //get google.maps.Circle object
        const map = $circleObject.getMap();
        map.fitBounds($circleObject.getBounds());
    })
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.vue-map-container {
  height: 640px;
}
</style>
```